# NGINX reverse proxy not redirecting to HTTP. All traffic forced to HTTPS

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I recently setup NGINX for the purpose of directing 2 domains I own to 2 different servers on my network, utilizing the same WAN address.

I currently have my firewall rules setup to simply pass port 80 traffic to the IP of my NGINX server.

Utilizing the following conf file with NGINX, ALL attempts to connect to any of my previously accessible sites now forces the URL typed into the browser to immediately change to HTTPS which is not what I want.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.domain1.net domain1.net;

   location /{
      proxy_pass http://192.168.50.226:8080;
   }
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.domain2.net domain2.net;

   location /{
      proxy_pass http://192.168.50.35:8080;
   }
}
```

The good news is that both domains are resolving to my WAN address which addressed my first problem. I now want them to natively go to their respective HTTP address, rather than it's current behavior of switching to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

For those that may run into a similar issue. If using pfsense or similar technologies for your router, I found the issue to be was that the router was using port 80 as well for it's web gui, which was then forcing http traffic to then use https. After change the router default GUI port to 8080, everything feel into place and started working.